# Ant and Classpath

Tags: java, ant

I just started to learn Java using Thinking in Java book, and have some troubles using ant.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and have openjdk 7 java installed. I also setup the CLASSPATH to be the code folder

When I run ant in code folder, this is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: JDK 1.4.1 or higher is required to run the examples in this book.
[CheckVersion]  at com.bruceeckel.tools.CheckVersion.main(Unknown Source)
```

However when I run java -version, this is the output:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

How to setup ant and classpath correctly?

*P/S: Thanks everyone for the help!!! I figured out why it fails to check the version.
The testing condition is "if(minor < '4' || point < '1')" in CheckVersion.java. Yet my version is 1.6.024, eventhough 6>4 but 0<1 that's why it failed. I guess we need to rewrite the testing condition!*

Comment: Do you have another JDK installed somewhere?  Try running, "ant -diagnostics" it will dump out all the environment, etc.

Comment: I think I currently have two JVM: update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1051 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the install directory of your 1.6 JDK.

When you type "java -version", the command shell is using the first java executable it finds in your PATH.  Ant probably looks for the java executable in the "bin" sub-directory of your JAVA_HOME directory.

---

To find the location of your java executable, type the following:

```
which java
```

and let's say you got the following output:

```
/usr/local/java1.6/bin/java
```

You would then set your JAVA_HOME variable to /usr/local/java1.6.  Assuming a Bourne or Bash shell, the syntax for that would be

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java1.6
```

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64: Is a directory

Comment: Can you verify that there the file "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" exists and has execute permission?

Comment: Given that there is definitely a 1.6 java installed (as proved when you entered "java -version"), please try setting your JAVA_HOME to point at that JVM.  I have edited my answer with instructions for doing that.

Comment: Not yet. Is it correct that I installed ant through apt-get install? If I compile and run CheckVersion.java separately, it shows that I'm having 1.6 version.

Comment: OK, does "java" have execute permission?  If this is not working for you, please try my suggestion in my last comment (setting JAVA_HOME to the 1.6 install).  T

Comment: I suspect your ant install is just fine.  Please try setting JAVA_HOME to your 1.6 install.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32654/discussion-between-dzung-nguyen-and-ejk)